# How do you create a video file upload form with Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, video, file-upload

I want a user to be able to upload a video from their computer or record it right from their webcam, then fill out other information with a form. I'm writing this app with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording directly from the web cam is not as simple as uploading an existing video file.  You may need to look into one of the many video streaming protocols and handle that via a server such as [red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/).  This approach would require the use of Flash or something similar.

Comment: +1 If the video will still be captured with a webcam, the red5 solution will be better in terms of ergonomy and for long recod. It's indeed quite harder to implement. There is a recent [github project](https://github.com/jfrec/jfrec/tree/master/Red5-version) for this purpose, it's just an alpha.

Answer (score 0):

The Django documentation should be able to help you handle file uploads:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly have a look at jquery uploadify. It's pretty useful for large file uploads because it display the progress of the download.